# How can i turn off the minus to zoom control in OpenLayers while using OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have a map using OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults but I also have a form next to the map that acepts coordinates. As is stands pressing '-' for a negative coordinate does not type but zooms the map out.

Is there a parameter I can add between the brackets of `new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()` that will allow me to turn off the listener for '-' while retaining all the other controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation for [OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/KeyboardDefaults-js.html) there is a property you can set called observeElement. This tells OpenLayers what DOM element of your page to listen for key events on. I'm guessing if this is not set it will listen on the whole page, and hence you get the actions occurring whereever you are. Maybe if you set this observeElement property to whatever your map div ID is (e.g. 'mapDiv') it will only listen when the map div is focussed. Something like

```
new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults({observeElement:'mapDiv'});
```

(you'll need to adapt this to wherever your keyboard defaults initialising code is)

I am only taking an educated guess here though and have not tried it myself, we use keyboard actions with forms on our own application with no problem, but we wrote a custom keyboard listener (so we could attach N to moving the map north, Esc to clear tooltips etc.) that, on key press, tested to see if an input, select or textarea was focussed and skipped the keyboard navigation if it was. A bit hacky but it worked. If the above doesn't work I'd be happy to share our code.

EDIT: Heres how we do it. Please note that this was custom written for our application. I've changed a few things to make it more generic, but some bits may require some customisation. Or you can rip out individual bits and add them into your own code. It looks scary but if you take it apart its quite simple, hopefully there should be enough there to help you get started.

```
var keyboardNavigation = {}; //we use a pluign approach, so our keyboard navigation plugin gets its own namespace
keyboardNavigation.moveFactor = 6; //this controls how far each key press moves the map
keyboardNavigation.pressed = false;
keyboardNavigation.keyPress = function (e, mapInstance, type) {
    if (!keyboardNavigation.pressed) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        var targetTagName = (target.nodeType == 1) ? target.nodeName.toUpperCase() : "";
        var found = false;

        var code;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
        //alert(character)

        //Check we are not focused on text box. Otherwise the map will be moving all over the place!
        if (!/INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/.test(targetTagName)) {

            if (character == "w") {
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
                mapInstance.pan(-mapInstance.getSize().w / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor, 0);
                found = true;

            } else if (character == "e") {
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
                mapInstance.pan(mapInstance.getSize().w / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor, 0);
                found = true;

            } else if (character == "n") {
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
                mapInstance.pan(0, -mapInstance.getSize().h / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor);
                found = true;

            } else if (character == "s") {
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
                mapInstance.pan(0, mapInstance.getSize().h / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor);
                found = true;

            } else if (character == "+" || character == "i") {
                // + or i
                mapInstance.zoomIn();
                found = true;

            } else if (character == "-" || character == "o") {
                // - or o
                mapInstance.zoomOut();
                found = true;

            } else if (code == 27) {
                // esc
                //do something with the esc key if you want
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }


    //Prevent default if found
    if (found || keyboardNavigation.pressed) {
        //Mouse pressed
        keyboardNavigation.pressed = true;
        //Prevent browser defaults like Opera's zoom in/out
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    }
};


//KeyUp event for arrow keys!
keyboardNavigation.keyUp = function (e, mapInstance, type) {

    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var targetTagName = (target.nodeType == 1) ? target.nodeName.toUpperCase() : "";
    var found = false;

    var code = e.keyCode;

    //Check we are not focused on text box. Otherwise the map will be moving all over the place!
    if (!/INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/.test(targetTagName)) {

        if (code == 37) { // west
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
            mapInstance.pan(-mapInstance.getSize().w / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor, 0);
            found = true;
        } else if (code == 39) { // east
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
            mapInstance.pan(mapInstance.getSize().w / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor, 0);
            found = true;

        } else if (code == 38) { // north
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
            mapInstance.pan(0, -mapInstance.getSize().h / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor);
            found = true;

        } else if (code == 40) { // south
                //your panning code goes here
                //this may not work as is as we use a custom function
            mapInstance.pan(0, mapInstance.getSize().h / keyboardNavigation.moveFactor);
            found = true;

        }
    }

    //Mouse up
    keyboardNavigation.pressed = false;

    //Prevent default if found
    if (found) {
        //Prevent browser defaults like Opera's zoom in/out
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    }
};


//Add key up listener to mapContainer
//'map' parameter is your map object that you referred to in your early initializing code
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(event){keyboardNavigation.keyPress(event,map,'document')});
    $(document).keydown(function(event){keyboardNavigation.keyUp(event,map,'document')});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this seems to turn of the controls for the map as well. Which seems odd.  Perhaps I have something wrong with my <div>? http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/cgi-bin/maps6.pl

If not it would be good to try your code if thats not a problem.

Comment: Weirdly, if I `tab` until I am focused on the OSM copyright, then you can use the keys. Odd. I'll post up what we did in a minute It'll probably take a bit ofwork to convert it to use with yours, but it should get you started.

Comment: @whatahitson Sample code from our application added. Have fun... ;)